# Insert Data from old SQL table, to new one with columns changed to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I currently have a table that looks similar to this:

[Old Table(example only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1JxQ.png)

I need to import the data to a new table, but making the column headers into rows and value for each one. Similar to this.

[New Table(example only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiSbZ.png)

Would I use a Pivot or an Unpivot to do this? I have a lot of columns with about 700 rows that need to be converted this way.

Comment: What software/language are you using ? What did you try ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go with `unpivot`, try the query below. Generally speaking, `Pivot` reduces the total number of rows while `Unpivot` increases it, instead.

```
select SN,Property,Value

from tbl

unpivot

(Value for Property in (Property1,Property2,Property3,Property4) ) as tblunpvt
```

Comment: So I tried your code above and it works fine when I run it with just Property1, but when I include anymore i get the following following error: The type of column "Property2" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: Never mind figured it out. All the columns need to be the same datatype. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have lot of columns you can always try something like :

```
SELECT SN, 'Property1' as Property, Property1 as Value from <TABLE>
UNION ALL
SELECT SN, 'Property2' as Property, Property2 as Value from <TABLE>
UNION ALL
SELECT SN, 'Property3' as Property, Property3 as Value from <TABLE>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I put in the question I have a lot of columns and rows.

Comment: I would agree that UNPIVOT is a great solution but it also sounds like this is a one time thing so lots of columns is sort of whatever...

Comment: if the columns really have that Property<n> format, it should be quite simple to create all the select statements in a Excel sheet :) But I get your point, if you can use a pivot/unpivot is a more refined way of doing it

Comment: @BrunoMarques They don't, it was just an example.

Comment: you can always get all column names from sys.columns and build the query using an Excel spreadsheet